# Will Jsoup and Selenium be on the same session?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, jsoup

Currently using Selenium with Java for some automation tests, the site has a reCaptcha implemented so to get around it i have to extract the site's key from the HTML so i could get it solved by a third party API (Anti-Captcha).
The site's key looks like this in the HTML file :

```
 <script type="application/json> 
          {siteKey : "SITE KEY HERE"} 
 </script>
```

To get around this i figured i should use Jsoup instead of Selenium's DOM manipulation methods, so i used this knowing that the siteKey's script tag is always 7th in the HTML :

```
        driver.get(siteUrl); // Selenium site connect.

        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(siteUrl).get(); // Jsoup site connect.

            // get site key for AntiCaptcha API
            Elements scripts = doc.getElementsByTag("script");
            int i = 0;
            for (Element script : scripts) {
                i++;
                if (i == 7) {
                    System.out.println(script.html());
                }
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

So what i am wondering is whether the site's key extracted by Jsoup is going to be the same as the one in the page that's being automated.

Comment: Well, it looks like you have now 2 objects - `driver` and `doc`. What holds you from printing the site's key from both and compare the values?

Comment: The loop is unneeded, you could just reference the 7th element of scripts. scripts[6]

Comment: Thank you @DMart i didn't know that was possible.

Comment: and no, i already printed the site's key it's just that the key changes each time you enter the site so having both Jsoup and Selenium would create two different key.